# Chrome-extension: Making a http request to a node.js server sending in cookie credentials (CORS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, google-chrome-extension, cors

I have been having some issues with my node.js server. I launched it using heroku and now I want my chrome extension to send http requests to the server (using cookies).

I am using express.js as my backend and I am having trouble setting up CORS the right way.

This is what I have in app.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: ['http://localhost:4200', 'http://localhost:8000', 'chrome-extension://kdfekbilmpafgiocanhihiogknfilcio']
  }));
} else {
  app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['chrome-extension://kdfekbilmpafgiocanhihiogknfilcio']
  }));
}

app.use(session({
 secret: 'angular shhh secret auth',
 resave: true,
 saveUninitialized: true,
 cookie : {
   httpOnly: true,
   expires: new Date(253402300000000)
 }
}));
```

and I am making requests from my chrome-extension (client) like this:

```
signUp(user) {
  const options = { withCredentials: true };

  return this.myHttp.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/signup`, user, options)
    .toPromise()
    .then((result) => {
      result.json()
  });
}
```

Aaand this is my error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
https://moodflowextension.herokuapp.com/loggedin. The value of the 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the 
wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 
'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The 
credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is 
controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I know I should pass in the cookie in the header somehow...

Comment: one issue seems to be that your server responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` - which is invalid when withCredentials is true (it says so, right there, in the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions and credentials require higher security in the form of not having wildcards in your header.

Fortunately, there is a way around this.

`var whitelist = [/yourDomain/];
var corsOptions = {
    origin: whitelist
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));`

This will make CORS only allow origins that contain yourDomain (which is a regexpression btw, not a string), without breaking credentials and sessions.

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, do I need to convert my domain string into a regular expression to achieve this? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: The whitelist can contain a mix of regexpressions and strings, e.g. [/google/, "example.com"] would make it match against any origin that contains google and the exact domain example.com. You're welcome :)